# Return all Users which match these search parameters

Tags: soql

I want to return all [Users](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) which match the Name and Title arguments I pass into my method. If the Name and Title arguments I pass in are empty, I would like to return *all* Users.

For example, if the Name I pass in is *John Smith* and the Title is *Manager*, I would like to return all *John Smiths* who are *Managers*. This works fine right now, but it's when I leave both fields blank, I have a problem.

At the moment, if Name and Title arguments I pass in are empty, my method is only returning Users who have a Name and Title, as opposed to Users who may have a Name but no Title.

```
@RemoteAction
public static Object searchForUsers(String name, String title) {

String soql = 'SELECT Id,Name,Title,UserType' +
                                        ' FROM user WHERE  IsActive = true ' +
                                        ' and (FirstName like \'' + name + '%\'' +
                                        ' or LastName like \'' + name + '%\')' +
                                        ' and Title like \'' + title + '%\'' + 
                                        ' and UserType = \'Standard\'  ' +
                                        ' ORDER BY Name ASC  LIMIT 201';

return SOQLQueryFLS.query(soql);
}
```

I suppose I could just wrap my query in an if statement and have a second query to accommodate both fields being empty, but I would like to know if I can just update my existing query in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on condition, prepare the where clause dynamically like below:

```
@RemoteAction
public static Object searchForUsers(String name, String title) {

    String soql = 'SELECT Id,Name,Title,UserType' +
        ' FROM user WHERE  IsActive = true ' + 
        ' and UserType = \'Standard\'';

    // add condition to query when name and title are not empty
    if(String.isNotEmpty(name) && String.isNotEmpty(title)) {
        soql += ' and (FirstName like \'' + name + '%\'' +
            ' or LastName like \'' + name + '%\')' +
            ' and Title like \'' + title + '%\'' + 
            ;
    }

    soql += ' ORDER BY Name ASC LIMIT 201';
return SOQLQueryFLS.query(soql);
}
```

Comment: Cheers @Daft, happy coding!